# Is it plausible for only living animals to be valid candidates for cloning?

Tags: biology, science-fiction, genetics, dinosaurs, extinction

So in my seting an alternate universe that's 67 million years "behind" ours, T. rex is on the brink of extinction early, with only 1 member left due to extreme overhunting by universe traveling humans.

An organisation needs to find this last living, breathing T rex in order to create clones that can rebuilt the decimated Laramidian ecosystem.

They can't use poached materials (like luxury T rex handbags) or dead individuals collected for science, because the universe traveling distorts the DNA of dead and dying organisms (but not living ones) and the infrastructure doesn't exist in the cretaceous human settlement to do intense genetic research.

Does this all check out?

Comment: This looks like a story set in your world and you're asking us to tell you how characters in your world could act to resolve the plot that you've constructed. Such questions are not a good fit for this site since plot happens in already built worlds.

Comment: Some more information on how your time travel works would be helpful; For instance, why can't they go back further in time and grab more T-Rexes from their past?

Comment: @sphennings this is *not* an already built world, that's why I'm asking this. I want worldbuilding reasons as to what they would do. I have none.

Plus, there isn't any other place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @user8796978 It's still an issue of plot. We also prohibit open ended questions with many valid answers. Currently you're asking us to list every way one could save a species, which meets our criteria for a too broad question.

Comment: @notovny It's basically punching holes through "soft parts" (gonna call them portals for convenience) of reality to go to adjacent alternate universes where the time is different. Most of these portals correspond relatively closely to irl mass extinctions. So there's also one for the Permian extinction, and the Carboniferous extinction etc... it's less time travel and more going to a place where time physically hasn't progressed as far.

Comment: It's extremely unclear how a single T.Rex is keeping the ecosystem from collapsing. With only one left, it has probably already started to collapse.

Comment: @sphennings okay well before you take it down could you let me edit it first?

Comment: @user8796978 We encourage users to [edit] posts. Even after a post is closed or deleted it can be edited by the poster. The first time you edit a closed post it automatically gets entered into a review queue where it will be considered for reopening, by community moderators.

Comment: You can read more about question closure, along with some explanation of why questions get closed in our [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: With your most recent edit you're leaning more into the decisions of characters by asking why would characters decide to not do a particular thing. That's unfortunately the wrong direction to go in if you're wanting to make this question a better fit.

Comment: @sphennings oh that's an amazing system! I'm used to reddit, sorry. Does my question fit the criteria now?

Comment: @JohnDallman well it is, the point is to rebuild the ecosystem Yellowstone style.

Comment: One notable quirk that trips up a lot of people is that because of the very structured format of this site questions asking for help brainstorming or generating ideas are prohibited. Even if you were to ask what facts about the world would prevent that course of action you'd be asking for idea generation which is considered too broad to be suitable.

Comment: @sphennings but I'm asking for a lore reason as to why they don't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138206/discussion-between-sphennings-and-user8796978).

Comment: Something to keep in mind: If the "only 1 member left" is meant literally, this is at odds with the requirement to find it. In order to know that there is only one left, whoever does the census basically requires planet-wide pinpoint scanning capability and would immediately know where this last specimen could be found.

Comment: @Surpriser which they have

Answer (score 11):

DWKraus has an [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/233646/2252) rooted in science fiction: Maybe only a T. Rex egg can be used to grow a baby T Rex.  As it turns out, we can make the same argument rooted in [science fact](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=3425):

> To answer your question, it does not appear to be possible to insert the somatic nucleus of an animal into the egg of an animal of a different species and generate a live clone. The reason for this is that development of an embryo is an incredibly sensitive process even in regards to naturally occurring fertilization. When an embryo initially begins to divide, many proteins present in the egg are responsible for ensuring that cell division occurs properly and that those cells begin to express the correct genes at the correct times

For present day cloners, your concerns are reality.

Comment: Yeah, DNA isn't a set of blueprints, it's more like a recipe. With blueprints, you can understand individual parts, and when something breaks, you can see where and why, you can replace parts at will and all that. With a recipe, either you follow it as closely as possible and get the right result, or you get something _completely_ different (usually junk). Using DNA of a different species is like trying to cook lentils in hard water taken up to eleven.

Comment: There’s nothing factually wrong with my answer, and calling it science fiction is rather personal.There’s a lot more about T Rex biology we don’t know than what we do. The rest is guesses based on other species. Besides, the question was extensively edited after I answered.

Answer (score 5):

## You need a female T Rex to grow T Rex eggs:

No other species than a T Rex can grow a T Rex egg in its body like a T Rex can. All the genetics in the world don't give you a species that produces T Rex eggs that will work as well as a T Rex. Even if your more advanced science could allow you to Jurassic Park an egg from another species, there are innumerable ways the real egg would work better.

Differentiation in non-reproductive cells will also mean that many regulatory signals and steps would need to be undone and “de-differentiated” which might work with more advanced tech, but which today we can’t even do with species we understand much better.

There's also a lot we DON'T understand about dinosaurs, that we may never know, since we can't study their direct biology. We have birds and reptiles, but maybe they don't accurately reflect how the dinosaurs really grew. Our deep ancestors could (we believe) see color, but because of an evolutionary bottleneck, all our direct ancestors were small mousy creatures that were color-blind. We have a completely re-evolved color system.

The same could be true for the T Rex. Their immune system could be involved in causing their eggs to harden enough to protect the contents. Or perhaps we don't understand some critical step of temperature control in the incubation process - something the female T Rex understands instinctively.

Or there is something unique about T Rex tissue - it's full of DNAse as a protection against ancient viruses that no longer exist, and all the DNA is rapidly broken down once the T Rex dies. But fresh tissue is essential to get intact DNA.

Comment: I'm sad this isn't a relevant answer anymore because these are such cool ideas :( don't change it tho, I'll copy it onto a google doc.

Comment: @user8796978 I was going to add epigenetics to this as well. Inherited non-genetic information and regulatory signals can easily be involved in development.

Comment: @user8796978 It really doesn't make any logical sense that DNA would experience physics differently because the organism is alive on not. What would the justification be for that? Is time travel mutagenic? It works if you have a perfect cure for cancer. BTW, The etiquette for completely changing a question is to close the existing question and submit a brand new one, generally.

Comment: sorry i didn't know that. Also i was imagining that the "mutagenic" properties of the travel does happen to living organisms, but it's usually negligible because you have an immune system to help correct most of the mutations, whereas a dead thing doesn't have that, so it's dna becomes unworkable. I'm not sure how much sense that makes now that I'm saying it though.

Comment: @user8796978 There are DNA repair mechanisms (not the immune system, except in the case of certain cancers) but any mutagenic condition that could affect dead tissue like that would likely be extremely harmful to living things also. The worse the damage, the sloppier the repairs get. It's why radiation causes cancer and mutation.

Comment: that's very true. I may just scrap this idea or come up with a plot device to help with it. Maybe like a super medicine that also cures cancer? Maybe it's *from* the dinosaurs and that's why poaching demand was so high? Ooooh what if they have to collect their white blood cells?! Thanks dude!

Comment: @user8796978 we do have evidence dinosaurs had cancer, since we can see telltale damage to bones from tumor growth.

Comment: well yeah but these are alternate universe dinosaurs, so I can say what I want tbf

Answer (score 4):

**Clone-quality DNA requires preservation.**

Real-life cloning projects use either fresh samples or specially preserved specimens that are usually frozen. A long-dead biological specimen might have degraded DNA that makes it unsuitable for cloning. Unless someone has a sample that has been specifically preserved in a manner suitable for a cloning project, you'll require a living organism to collect a viable sample.

Comment: To add to this, some numbers I came across while considering this for my answer.  DNA has a half life of 521 years.  That sounds like a long time, but with 3 billion nuclieotides in a human DNA strand (no idea what T.Rex had), that's about 4.5 million decomposition errors in the strand in the first year!

Answer (score 2):

Meet the [thylacine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thylacine).

We have plenty of thylacine specimens; the species went extinct at a time when museums were keen on preservation of endangered animals, and had no qualms in instructing hunters to endanger them further if it would bag them a pickled Tasmanian wolf. And yet, various [cloning projects have failed](https://web.archive.org/web/20081015173047/http://www.abc.net.au/news/newsitems/200502/s1303501.htm), on account of:

- the preservatives used to store their tissues (formaldehyde, ethanol, etc) degrade DNA and/or make it impossible to extract
- you need a mother thylacine, for developmental reasons already addressed by other answers
- even in ideal circumstances and with a surrogate mother, cloning is just quite difficult - [Dolly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_(sheep)) was the only survivor of 277 attempts. We've got better, and in some species there are reported clone survivorships over 50%, but these rates are obtained after *extensive* optimisations by trial and error, and with a conspecific mother.

In any case, one successfully cloned T-Rex (or a battery of them) a genetically viable population does not make, let alone an ecosystem-saving silver bullet. Do you want a justification for a T-Rex hunting story? Or is the focus on the actual ecological mission? If the latter, you really have to rethink your parameters. If the former, find another motivation for your characters.

Comment: The focus is on the ecological mission. I know that one new batch of rex eggs would not have enough genetic diversity to rebuild a population, but I was thinking that they could use preserved frozen rexes to "impregnate" the various new chicks with until a genetically viable population *does* exist.

Comment: Wait I thought you said the DNA doesn't survive travel? Where are these frozen rex specimens? Do you have a frozen seed bank? How did you collect it? *Do I want to know?*

Comment: yeah... I think I'm gonna get rid of that part